# How to specify InvariantCulture in string.join()?

Tags: c#, string, invariantculture

I have written the code below in which I am trying to convert an array of type `double` to a `string` value using `string.join()` method. And, then I am adding the string value as an attribute to an XML element.

```
        XElement element = new("TestNode");
        double[] myDoubleArray = new double[2] { 0.001, 1.0 };
        var stringValue = string.Join(" ", myDoubleArray);
        element.Add(new XAttribute("Values", stringValue));
```

The output of the above code is

> `<TestNode Values="0,001 1" />`

As can be seen, the value of `0.001` has been written as `0,001` because my system language is German.

**QUESTION:** How do I create a whitespace separated string from an array of double type (in minimum lines of code) while maintaining `InvariantCulture`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no string.Join overload that takes a CultureInfo parameter. Thus, you'll have to do the conversion yourself:

```
XElement element = new("TestNode");
double[] myDoubleArray = new double[2] { 0.001, 1.0 };

var myDoublesFormatted = myDoubleArray.Select(d => d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

var stringValue = string.Join(" ", myDoublesFormatted);
element.Add(new XAttribute("Values", stringValue));
```